# How can I make vim check automatically if the file has changed externally?

Tags: vim

I usually open many files in tabs with `vim -p`. Is it possible to check if any of the files was changed outside of Vim since editing started?

Comment: "Is it possible to check if any of the files was changed since editing started (e.g. by some external program)?" As it stands, your question is ambiguous. You should be able to remove statements in parenthesis without changing the meaning of the sentence. Please fix.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add these lines to your `.vimrc`:

```
au FocusGained,BufEnter * :silent! checktime
au FocusLost,WinLeave * :silent! w
```

Basically, check for and reload (or discard) external changes when Vim or the current buffer gains focus, and optionally, auto-save when leaving focus.

Source: [Vim Wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Have_Vim_check_automatically_if_the_file_has_changed_externally).

Answer (score 6):

I came across an interesting find related to this question today...

Hidden in `/usr/share/vim/vim71/vimrc_example.vim` there is this command:

```
" Convenient command to see the difference between the current buffer and the
" file it was loaded from, thus the changes you made.
command DiffOrig vert new | set bt=nofile | r # | 0d_ | diffthis
        \ | wincmd p | diffthis
```

It will open a `vimdiff`-like window with the current buffer and the underlying file highlighting all of the changes between the two.

Answer (score 3):

vim usually warns me automatically if it detects an external change to a file; however, from perusing the documentation it looks like you can invoke that check manually with `:checktime`

Unfortunately I don't know how to disable that aforementioned automatic check to test and see if checktime does the right thing, so this answer might be completely off-base.

Comment: `au CursorHold * checktime` - close to it. But I need to move the cursor for it to detect a change :(

Answer (score 2):

Use `:edit`

`:help :edit` for more info.

Answer (score 1):

You can find out if the buffer in the active window is modified by running the command:

```
:set mod?
```

If it returns `nomodified`, then the contents of the buffer match those of the corresponding file. If it returns `modified`, then the buffer has unsaved changes.

By default, the status-line shows a `[+]` symbol if the current buffer has been modified. The status line is generally only visible if you have split windows. If you want to show the status line, even when you have just a single window, run:

```
:set laststatus=2
```

There's a good article about [customizing your status line](http://vim.runpaint.org/display/changing-status-line/) on Vim Recipes.

Comment: I believe he means if the file on disk was modified by something other than vim since opening the file.

Comment: The question is poorly worded: the crucial detail I missed is in parenthesis. Thanks for the downvote.

Comment: Actually I have a [+] in the tabline if the file was modified

Answer (score 0):

```
let s:pid=system("ps -p $$ -o ppid=")+0
if !exists('g:watches')
    let g:watches={}
else
    finish
endif
function! ModWatch(fname, match)
    let fname=fnamemodify(a:fname, ':p')
    if has_key(g:watches, fname)
        return
    endif
    let shellscript=
                \"while true ; do".
                \"    inotifywait ".shellescape(fname)." ; ".
                \"    kill -WINCH ".s:pid." ; ".
                \"done"
    echo shellscript
    echo shellescape(shellscript)
    let pid=system("sh -c ".shellescape(shellscript)." &>/dev/null & echo $!")+0
    call extend(g:watches, { fname : pid })
    augroup ModWatch
        execute "autocmd! BufWipeOut ".a:match
        execute "autocmd BufWipeOut ".a:match.' call DeleteWatch("'.
                    \escape(fname, '\"|').'")'
    augroup END
endfunction
function! DeleteWatch(fname)
    call system("kill ".g:watches[a:fname])
    unlet g:watches[a:fname]
endfunction
augroup ModWatch
    autocmd!
    autocmd VimResized * checktime
    autocmd BufNew * call ModWatch(expand("<afile>"), expand("<amatch>"))
augroup END
```

Comment: Yes, on linux with inotify installed.